# Caesar cipher in Python

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

I wrote this looping Caesar cipher with a default key. I'd love for some input on how I could make this operate better/more effectively.

```
#Et Tu, Brute? [Caesar's Cipher]
#loops?
#Determine type of cipher...
doLoop=("y")
while doLoop==("y"):
#yep. loops.    
    det=input("Enter N for number or C for character; 'exit' to quit program ").lower() #lower case for simplicity! it don't care!
#Now the fun part!
#Numbers...
    if (det)==("n"):
        print("The default cipher key is 5")
        numRaw=input("Enter number to be decoded: ")
        if ord(numRaw)<ord("5"):
            numDec=ord(numRaw)+5
        else:
            numDec=ord(numRaw)-5
        print("The decoded number is: ",(chr(numDec)))

#Letters...
    if (det)==("c"):
        print("The default cipher key is 13")
        charRaw=input("Enter character to be decoded: ").lower() #lower case for simplicity!
        if ord(charRaw)<ord("m"):
            charDec=ord(charRaw)+13
        else:
            charDec=ord(charRaw)-13
        print("The decoded character is: " , (chr(charDec)))
    if det==("exit"):
        break
```

Comment: what's wrong with it now?

Comment: But I can say, you don't need those parentheses around your variables in your booleans: `(det)==("c")` => `det == "c"`

Comment: You probably wanted `<=ord('m')`, not `<`. Otherwise, you map `m` to a backtick instead of to `z` (which also means your cipher isn't reversible). Also, it's simpler to just use the `%` operator to wrap around `z` instead of trying to get the fiddly details right and introducing bugs like this one.

Answer (score 15):

Python strings have a [`translate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method that applies a substitution cipher. There is also a function [`str.maketrans`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) (`string.maketrans` in Python 2) that helps with building the translation table:

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet
>>> shift = 13
>>> cipher = str.maketrans(alphabet, alphabet[shift:] + alphabet[:shift])
>>> print("caeser salad is tasty".translate(cipher))
pnrfre fnynq vf gnfgl
```

of coarse in python2(with a shift of 13) one can simply do `"My Message".encode("rot13")`

Answer (score 5):

Register all the Caesar cyphers as [codecs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html). Codecs are actually quite easy to make – they consist of a function that takes an encoding name and returns either `None` if it doesn't know that codec name or a `CodecInfo` object if it does. In fact, `rot_13` is in the Python library in Python 2, so you can use that as a model.

```
import codecs

def search_function(encoding_name):
  try:
    name, rot = encoding_name.split('-')
    rot = int(rot, 10)
    if name != 'rot': return None
  except ValueError:
    return None
  rot = rot % 26
  offsets = [(i - rot) % 26 for i in range(26)]
  decoding_map = codecs.make_identity_dict(range(256))
  decoding_map.update((i, 65 + j) for i, j in enumerate(offsets, 65))
  decoding_map.update((i, 97 + j) for i, j in enumerate(offsets, 97))
  encoding_map = codecs.make_encoding_map(decoding_map)
  class Codec(codecs.Codec):
    def encode(self,input,errors='strict'):
      return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
    def decode(self,input,errors='strict'):
      return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_map)
  class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
    def encode(self, input, final=False):
      return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
  class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
    def decode(self, input, final=False):
      return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_map)[0]
  class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):
    pass
  class StreamReader(Codec,codecs.StreamReader):
    pass
  return codecs.CodecInfo(
    name='rot-{}'.format(rot),
    encode=Codec().encode,
    decode=Codec().decode,
    incrementalencoder=IncrementalEncoder,
    incrementaldecoder=IncrementalDecoder,
    streamwriter=StreamWriter,
    streamreader=StreamReader,
  )

codecs.register(search_function)

>>> for i in range(26): print letters.encode('rot-{}'.format(i))
... 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzaBCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA
cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAB
defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC
efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCD
fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdeFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDE
ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEF
hijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefgHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFG
ijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGH
jklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghiJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHI
klmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJ
lmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJK
mnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKL
nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM
opqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMN
pqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnoPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
qrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
rstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ
stuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
tuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrsTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS
uvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
vwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU
wxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV
xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW
yzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX
zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY
```

Comment: what is the value of using a codec rather than doing this some simpler way?

Comment: @Stuart what's the value of a Caesar cypher period?

Comment: @Stuart Anyway, there's a lot of power in codecs. They can be used to transform bytestrings, including just about any stream of data that needs transforming, and they are bidirectional. I can decode any Caesar cypher as easily as it was encoded. `'foo'.encode('rot-9').decode('rot-9') vs 'foo'.translate(maketrans(forward_shift)).translate(maketrans(backward_shift))`

Answer (score 2):

### Style

According to [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) you should:

- Limit your lines to <80 characters
- put spaces around your operators
- privilege underscore_names over camelCase for variables

There are trailing spaces on line 6, certain projects will refuse your code based on that.
You don't need parenthesis around values. `("y")` is equivalent to `"y"`, `(det)` to `det`, etc.

I would use more newlines to separate different parts of the code.

### Bad comments

The number one thing your code is lacking is proper commenting. The comments you give aren't very informative. In this case it doesn't matter much because the code is very easy to grasp, but practicing writing good and informative comments will definitely pay off. Also, you should (ab)use [doctests](http://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html).

### Comparing chars

You don't need to compare the `ord` of characters. Comparing strings is always alphabetical:

```
>>> "a" < "b"
True
>>> "b" < "a"
False
```

### Useless lines

```
doLoop=("y")
while doLoop==("y"):
```

The variable `doLoop` is never used.

Also, If you planned on using it as a flag to get out of the loop, a boolean would make more sense than a string.

### Repeated code

You're repeating the same logic twice. Why not make a function out of it and limit code duplication?